# PubNub EON not rendering History

Tags: charts, pubnub, c3.js

Unable to figure out why the EON spline chart is not loading history upon load (**Yes, the Storage and Playback features are enabled**) .  The chart will render data properly as data comes in and no errors are visible in the console.  Any clues as to what may be going on?

```
  eon.chart({
    channel: channel,
    history: true,
    flow: true,
    pubnub: pubnub,
    debug: true,
    generate: {
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        type: 'spline',
        labels: false
      }
    },
    transform: function(m) {
        return { eon: {
          'temp': m.temp
        }}
      }
  });
```

And here is the output from the console:

> ```
> EON-CHART: PubNub: Subscribed to runtimewareiotchannel
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: Status: Restoring from history
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: Retrieving messages from undefined
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: Status: Chart Animation Enabled
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: 10 messages found
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: Complete... Rendering
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: Retrieving messages from 14689036992721526
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: 1 messages found
> eon.js:7657 EON-CHART: History: Complete... Rendering
> ```

The data posted to PubNub is as follows - very simple:

```
{
  "temp": 76.662498
}
```

Thanks!
Derek

Comment: Someone from PubNub engineering will review this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary issue today and should be resolved. See this example:
http://pubnub.github.io/eon-chart/examples/history.html

Comment: It's fixed!  Thank you very much!